# Pre compile a directive for use in Google Maps marker causes '$apply already in progress' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am creating an AngularJS app that integrates with google maps. I have some html to use as an info popup. I use a similar chunk of html elsewhere in my app, so I started using a directive to create a re usable component.

Once I had implemented this I realised that the info popup windows need to be initialised with their html at time of creation not at time of 'popping up'.

I investigated how to pre compile a directive. It was much the same as the AngularJS docs on testing a directive.

```
var element = angular.element("<my-directive data=data></my-directive>");
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
scope.data = someData;
element = $compile(element)(scope);
scope.$apply();

element.html(); // Gives me the html
```

This causes the error **'$apply already in progress'** I know that it means that a digest cycle is already in progress but this $apply is necessary as I need to create this precompiled template to pass to my info popup.

I have looked into $interpolate and $parse but I don't think I can use these as my directive has link functions that need to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (!$scope.$$phase)
 $scope.$apply();
```

Comment: No was looking for some other way of compiling or using an isolate scope. I've seen many answers using that technique and didn't want to do that. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can do safeapply(see below code), but its **not recommended**

https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma/safe-apply-in-angular-js

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
  var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
  if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
    if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    this.$apply(fn);
  }
};
```

Comment: Hmm yes I've seen this elsewhere as well but was wanting to avoid having to do any scope phases checking .

Comment: @user3406268 I don't see you doing any asyc operation in code then why do you need scope.$apply() there.

Comment: To force the directives scope expressions to be evaluated. See testing directives section here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Comment: have you used `ng-app` or `angular.module` anywhere in your tests?

Comment: This is happening in my app not my test suite. I was using the test documentation as a guide as it showed how to compile a directive 'programatically'